# JQuery Validate input file type (type and size)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Want to validate image type (png), and size. (800X600)
I have that html `<form>`:

```
<form action="@Url.Action("UploadImage", "CreditCard")" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadForm">
                   <fieldset>
                       <input type="file" class="filestyle" accept=".png" data-buttonName="btn-primary" name="imageUploaded" />
                       <br>
                       <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Upload">
                   </fieldset>
               </form>
```

And that JS:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>

$("#uploadForm").validate({
            rules: {
                imageUploaded: {
                    accept: "image/png"
                }
            }
        });
```

I want the validate to occur when "Submit" button click.

Comment: Ok. It seems that you covered the extension, right? You just need the size/resolution?

Comment: The extension not work too, is my syntax ok? Yes i need size too